# Recursion If Statement assistance

Tags: java, recursion

Why does:

```
public static void splat(String s)
{
    if (s.length() < 8)
    {
        splat(s+s);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

not print out ********

when splat("**") is called

Comment: Have you debugged into it to see what's happening?

Comment: it will, but it will also print `****` and `**` afterwards. Take @JonSkeet 's advise and debug it

Comment: It is generally useful for you to include the actual output that you are seeing.  Tell us what you're doing, what you are seeing, and what you expect to see if it is different.

Answer (score 2):

each time splat is called System.out.println(s); is executed so the output will be

```
********
****
**
```

to print out only ******** do like this:

```
public static void splat(String s)
{
    if (s.length() < 8)
    {
        splat(s+s);
    }
    else 
    { 
       System.out.println(s);

     }
}
```

Comment: why does it start by printing ******** instead of starting with **

Comment: @Rolando because the println is after the method call, it will keep doubling 's' until it is no longer less than 8. Then the first println will execute.

Comment: Because  System.out.println(s); is not reached until splat("********").

Comment: @hasnae so then why does it go backwards and print out **** then **

Comment: As  Spencer4134 explained  , when splat("********") is reached it print out "********" and the execution of splat("****") continue with printing out "****" an so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your result is:

```
********
******
****
...
```

Since you're printing within the function.

If you move println out of the function you should get the desired result with a return

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(splat("**"));
}

public static String splat(String s){
    if (s.length() < 8){
        s = splat(s+s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have included the output. I have run this and will put it here:

```
********
****
**
```

The reason is that when you recall the method like that, the first time the if statement comes out false, it will print the '********' as expected. But the it will *pick up where it left off* on the last call, which means it will run that println again with s being '****'. Finally, it will run the original call where s is '**'.

Instead of recalling the method, you should use a loop to actually change the value of s with `s = s + "**";`

For example, use this instead of the if statement:

```
while (s < 8)
s += "**";
```

This will run until 's' is '********'

Hope this helps!